# Lazy Load html video with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, html5-video

I am trying to lazy load my html video. It's in my WordPress template and I want for video to load when user get to its viewpoint.

I am new in JS so  I think something is wrong. How can I test if lazy loading is working correctly?
Maybe my function is not valid?

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay loop muted playsinline src="<?= VIDEO ?>/video_footer.mp4">
    <source data-src="<?= VIDEO ?>/video_footer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
$("video.myVideo source").each(function() {
    var sourceFile = $(this).attr('data-src');
    $(this).attr("src", sourceFile);
    var video = this.parentElement;
    video.load();
    video.play();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think in your case you can use a micro plugin like http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/ 
It is without jQuery, very lightweight and efficient. It will also work with video tag.

Comment: Try https://www.sitelint.com/blog/improved-lazy-loading-for-image-video-and-audio/

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that is working as it is.

You have already set the `source` to `video` so even if the function is working, the video file is already there, so no lazy load...

**This is the correct setup:**

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay loop muted playsinline src="">
    <source data-src="<?= VIDEO ?>/video_footer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then you can check if you function works

---

**Another solution** is to use `intersection observer` and do it with `pure JavaScript`, simple, lightweight and works in most cases

**Lazy load video with pure JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const lazyvideo = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-video');
observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      console.log('video in the view');
         if (entry.target.querySelector('source').getAttribute('data-src') !== null) {
          const source = entry.target.querySelector('source').getAttribute('data-src')
          entry.target.setAttribute('src', source);
        }
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    } else {
      console.log('video out of view');
    }
  });
});

lazyvideo.forEach(video => {
  observer.observe(video);
});
</script>
```

I have added `console.log('video out of view');` & `console.log('video in the view');` in order to check the console whether the video is in view or not.

With this script if you want a video to be lazy loaded, just add a `class lazy-video` to it and you are all set ;)

**Full code:**

```js
const lazyvideo = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-video');
observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      console.log('video in the view');
         if (entry.target.querySelector('source').getAttribute('data-src') !== null) {
          const source = entry.target.querySelector('source').getAttribute('data-src')
          entry.target.setAttribute('src', source);
        }
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    } else {
      console.log('video out of view');
    }
  });
});

lazyvideo.forEach(video => {
  observer.observe(video);
});
```

```css
#myVideo {
  max-width:400px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" class="lazy-video" autoplay loop muted playsinline src="">
    <source data-src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you want to be sure that lazy load works

- Open you Chrome developer tools and go to `Network` and select the
  `media` tab
- While you have the tools open reload the page
- If you haven't scroll to the video section then you should not see
  the video in your console
- While you scroll when you are in the view of the video section then
  you must see the video loading on the media tab

**See screenshots below:**

Not there yet:

[image]

In view:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for replay. I have issues. with the code. "Uncaught ReferenceError: observer is not defined" as console mistake and when I exclude video from src in video tag and leave it just in source tag it does not show. @kaize

Comment: Try to add the script to you footer or after the video

Comment: Now it works but how can I know that video is loading EXACT when I scroll on video section? @kaize

Comment: It works but if you want to be sure I updated my answer check the last part